# What is the api to get the bamboo - plan list(In a project) and last successful build number?

Tags: api, build, bamboo

Looking for an api to fetch the plan list from a specific project in bamboo. Also the last successful build number for a specific plan.

Comment: I am able to get the plan list from a specific project by using the below but unable to find the last successful build number in a specific plan.

http://<bamboo-server:port>/rest/api/latest/project?expand=projects.project.plans.plan

Answer (score 0):

For finding the last successful build, use https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-bamboo/REST/6.10.4/#d2e1133

```
$ curl --user ... https://.../bamboo/rest/api/latest/result/PROJECT-PLAN.json?buildstate=successful | \
    jq .results.result[0].number
1292
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. I am able to get the complete list of builds for a specific plan using the below but unable to get the last successful build .

https://.../bamboo/rest/api/latest/result/PROJECT-PLAN.json?buildstate=successful

Is there any other way to get it other than jq .results.result[0].number

Comment: No. Even if you supply `max-result=1`, you'll always have to extract the build number from the returned json `results.result`.